# Repeated Regularized Least Squares

Tags: regression, regularization, linear

Regularized Least Squares (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularized_least_squares) is a well-studied problem, but I'm having trouble finding any references on what happens if one iteratively computes the optimal parameters replacing the regression target with the previous iteration's predicted values.

For concreteness, suppose we solve

$$w_1 = \arg \min_w \frac{1}{2}||X w - Y||_2^2 + \frac{c}{2}||w||_2^2$$

which gives predicted values

$$ Y_1 := X w_1$$

And then solve

$$w_2 = \arg \min_w \frac{1}{2}||X w - Y_1||_2^2 + \frac{c}{2}||w||_2^2$$

which gives predicted values:

$$ Y_2 := X w_2$$

And so on, $n$ times. What can be said about the parameters $w_n$ or predictions $Y_n$?

I think the predictions have the following form:

$$Y_n = \Big( X (X^T X + c I)^{-1} X^T \Big)^n Y $$

What can be said about the matrix product $\Big( X (X^T X + c I)^{-1} X^T \Big)^n$?

Comment: Don’t you get perfect predictions as soon as you replace the observed $y$ with the first iteration’s predictions?

Comment: Write $H_\lambda = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} X^T X$. The first iteration has predictions $H_{\lambda_1} y$. The second has predictions $H_{\lambda_2} \left( H_{\lambda_1} y \right)$, and so on. Studying products of these matrices $H_{\lambda_k}$ will give the answer.

Comment: @Dave, if the regularization term is 0, then yes, you'd be correct, but user551504 has the right idea. I was hoping someone can point me towards some references of people who have studied these products of matrices?